# Export Derby db as a sql file

Tags: java, database, export, derby

I have a derby db in "D:/Dev/workspaces/workspacePro/School-FinMa/school-finma". I want to export it to a this folder "E:/". So I run this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java org.apache.derby.tools.dblook -d 'jdbc:derby:D:/Dev/workspaces/workspacePro/School-FinMa/school-finma' -o 'E:/myDB_DDL.sql'");
```

But nothing happens, it's like if this code does not exists.

I want a way to export the db to single .sql file, that contains all db generation code + data. How Can I do that from inside Java ??

The project (in eclipse) have derbytools.jar imported.

Comment: Is the same command working from command line? Do you read the output and error streams of the process? Are there any errors?

Comment: dblook will only export your "schema" -- a bunch or `CREATE TABLE`, `CREATE INDEX`, `CREATE VIEW`, etc statements -- not the database tables themselves. It sounds like you would like to make a **backup** of your database?

Comment: :vanje: there is no error no output, nothing. I used this command in cmd and it works: dblook -d 'jdbc:derby:D:/Dev/workspaces/workspacePro/School-FinMa/school-finma' -o 'myDB_DDL.sql' But I want the application (user) to be able to do this not me from the command line.

Comment: :bryan so how can i do full back up as you said?

Comment: "Is the same command working from command line?" No, it prints: Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.derby.tools.dblook

Answer (score 0):

When you start a new sub process and it doesn't work, you should output the output and error streams. You said there is no output, but I think you didn't get the output stream of the process.

When running a Java sub process you should add the classpath as you would in the command line. In this case you should add `derby.jar` and `derbytools.jar`. For a network connection you need `derbyclient.jar`, too.

You are using Windows. Then don't use single quotation marks.

Here is a simple running example, which prints the output and error streams to the console. Without an error there is no output. But try it with single quotation marks you will see an error message.

In this example the Derby JARs are located at: `e:\derby\lib`.

```
public static void copyStream(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
  final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int bytesRead = 0;
  while((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( 
    "java -cp e:\\derby\\lib\\derby.jar;e:\\derby\\lib\\derbyclient.jar;e:\\derby\\lib\\derbytools.jar org.apache.derby.tools.dblook -d jdbc:derby:D:/Dev/workspaces/workspacePro/School-FinMa/school-finma -o E:/myDB_DDL.sql");
  final int exitValue = process.waitFor();
  System.out.println("Exit value: " + exitValue);

  System.out.println("Outputstream: ");
  copyStream(process.getInputStream(), System.out);

  System.out.println("Errorstream: ");
  copyStream(process.getErrorStream(), System.out);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But no data is there in the backup, only the schema.

Comment: Used the code above along with the jar-files shipped with a 3'rd party product. It failed complaining about missing locale. Got it working by downloading Derby from Apache website, where the local jar-files are present and then the code worked. That is - I now got to read the error message saying I have to stop the 3'rd party product first so DB is  not in use.